# Is it a good programming practice to use views instead of tables in database management

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I am developing an application and I have a very complex query, to simplify the querying process I decided to use an sql view, to store the query data so that I can easily query the complex query's data from the view. The function works and it displays the data that I want.
What I really like to do is, is it the best practice to use views instead of tables to query information from the database.
Thanks

Comment: View is usually good in two cases. 1) when you want some user to see only limit record. 2) when a query takes time to process, then you create a ready to use view for that. (conditioned record is not meant to change frequently). So I guess it might help you in your case

Comment: And is it true that views consume unnecessary space in the database and can sometimes lead to database inconsistency ?

Comment: materialized views consume space, not normal views. Google about the difference between materialized view and simple view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In specific use cases views are a perfectly acceptable way to simplify application logic by encapsulating complex queries within the database. I see nothing wrong with what you have described.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular views offloads the database query writing and optimization onto the potentially more experience DBA responsible for the core database itself.

Using a view effectively migrates the business logic of a query into the database layer where the rules can be centrally inforced independent of any one application.
The DBA can optimize a view for performance or data integrity reasons without forcing a refactoring of the application as long as the view continues to meet the same result set.

Having a view allows a DBA to review and optimize where feasible.
Also if not using views the long query will have to be sent and parsed each time your request data.  A view is quasi pre-parsed on creation of the view and will save that time.